# wpf Оператор "==" невозможно применить к операнду типа "int" и "int[]"

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core, access

Как мне загрузить таблицу сделав проверку через where id из базы данных сравнить с массивом id?

```
ErrorDataGrid.ItemsSource = MainWindow._context.Question.Where(t => t.id == idQustErrors.ToArray());
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains

Comment: Вам четко в ошибке написано, что вы сравниваете int с массивом. Не делайте так, и ошибки не будет.

Comment: это все равно, что сравнивать номер автобуса с автобусным парком)

Comment: А как возможно сравнить int и int[] в данной ситуации?

Comment: Вам ответ ниже дали, как. Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем понятно но думаю что-то такое хотели сделать

```
ErrorDataGrid.ItemsSource = MainWindow._context.Question.Where(t => idQustErrors.Any(id => id == t.id));
```

Comment: очень похоже на правду